# How can I edit and tamper packets at will?

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

What tools or options do I have so that I can edit or tamper with Wireshark/tcpdump captures in any way which I want- be it IP headers, TCP layer, the payload part or raw packets? I have looked at [Scapy](https://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) and [libcrafter](http://code.google.com/p/libcrafter/). [Netdude](http://netdude.sourceforge.net/) is great as well, but the project is not maintained by the author.

What better options are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one tool which, although a little slow, nearly fulfills the above said requirements.

It is [Power edit pcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/powereditpcap/)

Answer (score 2):

Some useful tools I have tried are [Editcap](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html), [pktanon](http://www.tm.uka.de/software/pktanon/), [tcprewrite](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/tcprewrite), and [bittwist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I have used pktanaon- it is an anonymization tool. Editcap and tcprewrite also don't serve the purpose because, I guess, they simply re-write the packet for that layer and do not allow me to edit as I may like (say change some stuff in the payload). Yet to see bit-twist...Thanks. I liked Netdude, but the project isn't maintained I guess.